# Replace lines by line number with lines from other file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I'm searching for an elegant way to replace a block of lines in ASCII-file1 with all lines of file2 beginning with the 2nd line. The lines to be replaced in file1 are encapsulated within blank line nr.2 and nr.3 .

The numbers of the first and the last line of the block in file1 are fix for a bunch of files, but a more general solution would be desirable.

file1:

```
first
text
block
                        #blank line
second textblock
                        #blank line
third
text
block
                        #blank line
```

file2:

```
first line
all
the 
other
lines
```

expected file1 after replacement:

```
first
text
block
                        #blank line
second textblock
                        #blank line
all
the 
other
lines
                        #blank line
```

Comment: You'd better post some input and desired output.

Comment: where are you indicating that file2 corresponds to the third text block?

Comment: Oh! I din't... Sry, my fault.

Comment: Is the text "first line" actually present in file2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is about reading a file by paragraphs:

```
awk 'NR==3 {while (getline < "file2") print; next} 1' RS='' ORS='\n\n' file1
```

or

```
perl -00 -pe '$.==3 and $_=`cat file2`."\n"' file1
```

Answer (score 3):

One way with `awk`:

```
$ match="second textblock"

$ awk 'NR==FNR&&!p;$0~m{print p;p=1};NR>FNR&&FNR>1' m="$match" file1 file2
first
text
block
                     #blank line               
second textblock

all                  #blank line
the 
other
lines
                     #blank line
```

Answer (score 3):

#### GNU sed

```
sed '2,$!d' file2 > file3
sed -f script.sed file1
```

---

`script.sed`

```
/second textblock/{
n
r file3
q
}
```

--
The output is:

```
first
text
block

second textblock

all
the
other
lines
```

Comment: The shell won't like `$!` you should quote your script.

Comment: No problem, I'm on Windows :)

Comment: The question is tagged `bash` ;)